# Test Spring REST service with Spring security on SoapUI

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, soapui

I'm have a Spring service like this:

localhost:8889/projectX/insurance/?policy=1

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="insurance")
public class InsuranceService {

            @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            public List<Policy> getPolicy(@RequestParam(value="policy") int policy){
           ...
    }
 }
```

That produces a JSON with a policy info.

In WebSecurityConfig.java i have this security:

```
       @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/insurance/**").access("hasRole('advicer')")
            ...
```

So if I try to consume that service on SoapUI I will be directed to login form

[image: SoapUi]
How can I consume that service correctly with authentication?

Comment: It is not REST if it requires form authentication.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending cookie as request header in SOAP UI request for rest web service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022721/sending-cookie-as-request-header-in-soap-ui-request-for-rest-web-service)

Answer (score 1):

I would switch off security for Junit testing, with a profile.

In your WebSecurityConfig.java file add

```
@Profile("default")
```

Then for non security testing either in Junit use

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
```

Or from a server add to your server start up

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=test
```