# SoapUI to manage cookies

Tags: http, soapui, session-cookies, jsessionid

I use code below to get value of `JSESSIONID` from request in `SoapUI`.

```
def setCookie = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Request1"].testRequest.response.responseHeaders["Set-Cookie"]
re = /(JSESSIONID=[A-Za-z0-9]+)/
matcher = ( setCookie =~ re )
def jsesid = matcher[0][0]
log.info "$jsessid"

props = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties");
props.setPropertyValue('cookie',"$jsessid");
```

I put this variable in other requests' headers, but get a new JSESSIONID in response. So I lost session, because a new one is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have already come across the description of a similar issue at [Sending cookie as request header in SOAP UI request for rest web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022721/sending-cookie-as-request-header-in-soap-ui-request-for-rest-web-service).

Besides this, you'd need to set the [`Maintain HTTP session`](https://www.soapui.org/soapui-projects/form-based-authentication.html) in the option for your test case.